# Android: Scaling drawables relative to screen size

Tags: android, image, drawable, scaling, percentage

novice Android programmer here.

I am trying to make a map, consisting of several images. I got the layout working fine, but I am having a lot of trouble with scaling these images. I have googled and tried several solutions, but none have solved my problem, so I turn to you guys.

If I want to have an image that for instance has its width as 10% of the screen width, and its height as 5% of the screen height, how do I implement this?